# MYSQL sub query performance inconsistency

Tags: mysql, subquery

G-day,

I'm somewhat puzzled by the following.
When I run this query it takes a very long time to resolve:

```
Select *
from test
where id in (select id from test2 where customer = 'HARRY');
```

When I run the sub query by itself it resolves to '13454' in a spit second.
When I change the main query's where statement to in ('13454') it also resolves instantly.

Someone have any idea why it won't run in it's original format??

Cheers,

Rene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is a quirk of MySQL.  The subquery is executed for each row of the outer table.

To fix this, use `exists`:

```
Select *
from test
where exists (select id from test2 where test2.customer = 'HARRY' and test2.id = test.id);
```

This will work most efficiently if you have an index on `test2(customer, id)`.

I should add that this depends on the version of MySQL (I think it is fixed in 5.5).  The older [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html) explains it as:

> Consider the following subquery comparison:
>
> outer_expr IN (SELECT inner_expr FROM ... WHERE subquery_where)
>
> MySQL
> evaluates queries “from outside to inside.” That is, it first obtains
> the value of the outer expression outer_expr, and then runs the
> subquery and captures the rows that it produces.

Answer (score 0):

use `JOIN`

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    Test a
        INNER JOIN Test2 b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE   b.customer = 'Harry'
```

For faster performance, make sure that `ID` on both tables have `KEY` on them.